# Strong Markov property explained.

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have got 2 theorems,

**Theorem 1**
The increment $ (N_{t+u} - N_t)_{u\geq 0} $ of a Poisson process rate $\lambda$ is again a Poisson process rate $\lambda$ and is independent of $(N_s)_{0\leq s \leq t}$

**Proof**

$ P(N_{t+u} - N_t)= k|N_t=n, T_1=t_1,....T_n=t_n) $

$= P(N_{t+u} - N_t)= k) $

$= p_u (0,k) $

**Theorem 2** 
The strong Markov property

$N = (N_t)_{t\geq0} $is a Poisson process rate $\lambda$

Let T be a stopping time

Define  $N^T $ via $N^T_t = N_{T+t} - N_T $

Conditional on T being finite $(N^T_t)_{t\geq 0} $ is a Poisson process rate $\lambda$ which is independent of $ (N_t)_{0\leq t \leq T}$

Can anybody

A) explain the first proof why does it hold?

B) explain exactly how these 2 theorems are different?

Comment: @Shyam I think the problem is that my lecturer has defined a poisson process as a counting process such that $ (N_t)_t\geq 0$ is markov and q(x,x+1) = lambda,q(x,y) = 0 for y not in {x,x+1} (whereas I know most definitions define it as having independent increments etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The first proof is a direct consequence of the [independent increment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_increments#Independent_increments) property of Poisson processes: the number of arrivals in $(t,t+u)$ is independent of $N_t$.

Strong Markov property is a result which states that the Markovian property of Theorem 1 not only holds for **deterministic** times, but also for some particular **random** times, which are called [stopping times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time).

Strong Markov is a useful and strong extension of Markovity in Poisson processes, DTMCs and CTMCs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am still a bit confused.
So does the proof prove not that the increments are independent but that they form a poisson process rate lambda?
Also if the increments are independent i.e.the number of arrivals in (t,t+u) is independent of $ N_t $ then I can see that $N_{t+u} - N_t$ doesnt depend on $ N_t $ but how do we know that $N_{t+u} - N_t$ doesnt depend on $T_1, ...T_n$?

Comment: @Rosie: are you the same Rosie as the one who asked the question? If so, please visit [our account merge page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to consolidate your accounts. That way you will be able to comment on answers to your own questions.